# Is there a way to nest links with the link field?

Tags: 8

Working on a project where a sub menu uses the link field. Now they want a dropdown, but my drupal experience is extremely limited and google doesn't give me anything. I know you can with actual menus, but there doesn't seem to be a way to nest links in the link field. Am I forced to use a menu instead?

Comment: Menus are hierarchical, a link field is just a field. Having done hundreds of menus... go the menu route.

Comment: Historically Drupal had menus (since the beginning) before it had a concept of a link field.  Therefore the tools for working with menus are way more extensive.